# Combining Objective-C and C/C++ on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, macos, gcc

Can I create an Objective-C library (by XCode) and use it in my C/C++ application (compiled by GCC without supporting Objective-C).

Comment: What do you mean without supporting Objective-C?  Do you mean without supporting Apple Framework/SDK?

Comment: I mean my objective-c code, does not compiled in gcc. I should write c/c++ source code not objective-c.

Comment: Xcode is using gcc(or llvm) to compile your objective-c code, I don't understand.

Comment: I don't use XCode, I use codeblocks IDE that my source code should be C/C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a C or C++ interface for your Objective-C code, so you can use this interface to call the Objective-C code from your C/C++ code. Note that you can take advantage of Cocoa's toll-free bridging: e.g. you can return an NSString* and interpret it as a CFStringRef in your C/C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this tool (it's fairly raw at the moment) to generate C/C++ bindings for Objective-C code (created to help get Wine [C only] code working with OSX[Objective-C] libraries).

This email explains how the tool came about and has the binding generating code as an attachment.

http://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2011-April/089657.html
The download is actually a tar.gz.

You could give it a shot yourself and then try emailing Charles about using it if it's too much trouble (and bug him to set it up as a proper project somewhere.  :-)